# Does a direct flight emit more CO2 than a flight with a layover?

Tags: air-travel, layovers, flight-search-engines, environment

On Google Flights, I searched the FRA-JFK route:

[image: screenshot with three flights]

It surprises me that a flight with a layover emits so much less [CO<sub>2</sub>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_dioxide) than a direct flight, as many times I've heard the suggestion that the takeoff is the most polluting phase of the flight and so flights with layovers are more polluting than direct flights.

Might there be something wrong with Google's assessment or is that "rule of thumb" bad advice?

Comment: Are they all the same class of plane for the longer distance? In the KLM listing I see cityhopper which usually does the within Europe flights.

Comment: If the AF and KLM flights use more recent planes like a 787 or 350 that probably makes a big difference. But apparently the most efficient one is a direct flight Condor flight (not shown here) using an A330neo

Comment: Well, shame on me, I was just looking out of curiosity and didn't save the dates I used for the query, so I can't see the specific aircraft involved. But then I guess that's the answer... Didn't expect the aircraft to make such a decisive difference.

Comment: I did find other instances of this KLM Cityhopper for that route though, e.g. for 2 Nov, FRA-AMS is Embraer 190 and AMS-JFK is a Boeing 787-10, in total with 64 + 361 = 425 kg CO2 emissions.

Comment: There is literally an (I)nfo button in your screenshot. Click on that and it'll tell you why this is the case (hint: it includes things like type of aircraft/speed/number of passengers/etc, not just distance).  This doesn't deserve an answer when the answer is right there...

Comment: Also consider outright lies by the airline - they may "use a different calculation" because having a lower figure is more attractive to end-users.  You're looking at these numbers and making a potential purchasing decision here.  Cynical, yes.   Plausible, also yes.

Comment: All answers so far are based on traveling in a more or less straight line with an extra stop at a sensible point. Many of the itineraries i have seen fly you to and from a hub and away from it where the different options all add miles as well as an extra stop. Like Amsterdam to Paris to Boston, or Paris to Amsterdam to Boston both being cheaper than the direct flights Amsterdam Boston or Paris Boston. No way those cheaper options are better in regards of emissions.

Comment: When I search the same flights again, I get different numbers: +86% for the Delta flight, and +31% for the KLM. Probably take the numbers with a large amount of salt.

Comment: @fishinear, please note that I myself lost the dates I used as input to get those results. So it could be that the airplanes are different for your date.

Comment: @Criggie, apparently those figures are not provided by the airline, they are calculated by Google. Though I guess they could lie about less easily verifiable data, e.g. the amount of "sustainable fuel"

Comment: The one with the layover doesn't have to carry the fuel for the whole journey from the beginning which may make a difference?

Answer (score 19):

As the comments said: the CO₂ estimates depends a lot on the aircraft and other factors. The actual calculation is rather complicated and so Google (and others) have to make a lot of simplifying assumptions.

For the aircraft, it's the fuel efficiency but also the seating arrangement. For example, a Boeing 777 can have 3-3-3 or 3-4-3 seating in economy. Obviously 3-4-3 is more efficient since you cram more passengers into the same space, but it's also a miserable flying experience, so pick your poison.

This being said the numbers that Google provides here seem unrealistic to me. Fuel is the second largest expense for airlines so they are highly incentivized to optimize fuel efficiency. I doubt that KLM can operate a transatlantic flight 40% more efficient than Delta. If that were the case, Delta would be out of business by now.

> and so flights with layovers are more polluting than direct flights.

Surprisingly that's not always the case. Above a certain distance it's more efficient to add a fuel stop. For a Boeing 777 that's about 4500km.

Comment: [Wikipedia tell us](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuel_economy_in_aircraft#Medium-haul_flights): A220-300 = 2.02 l/100 km/seat, 767-200ER in 181 seats configuration = 3.34 l/100 km/seat. Which would result in savings of exactly 40%. Given the aircraft involved here it should be less, though, but there may be differences in the way this is computed.

Comment: KLM is using some (expensive) synthetic fuel mixed in, and also offers carbon compensation by planting trees. Maybe that's incorporated here?

Answer (score 12):

In this specific case, the savings are most likely due to the type of aircraft involved. More recent aircraft such as a 787, 350, or 330neo can be a **lot** more fuel efficient than older aircraft. This comes mostly from more efficient engines, but also from improvements in aerodynamics (the winglets and other tip-of-wing optimisations have surprisingly important effects), or weight optimisations (787s and 350s use a lot of composite materials and are lighter).

There could also be differences in cabin configuration. A denser configuration (smaller row pitch or more seats per row) will result in better efficiency per seat (that's possibly one of the reason the Condor flight on that route shows such a higher efficiency).

If one wants to go into details for a very specific flight (i.e. on a specific date), the exact route flown, and the influence of jet streams can radically change things as well. You could also consider saturation at the airports involved (both in the air and on the ground).

In the more general case, the computation is complex, and it's hard to say that, even with the exact same plans, a direct flight is always necessarily more fuel efficient than one with a stop: while the take-off phase is indeed quite fuel-hungry, and having one rather than two should be better, a direct flight requires more fuel to be carried on board, which weighs a lot, and which will have an impact on the overall fuel consumption.

For instance, an A350-900ULR has a maximum take-off weight of about 280 tons. Out of that, there could be up to 135 t (nearly half!) for fuel, for a flight at max range/payload. The quantity of fuel depends on the distance (but it's not linear as indeed there's a larger need during take-off), so the aircraft would be lighter during most of the flights, and would use less fuel. I know the question has been raised again recently with the recent and upcoming Europe-Australia direct flights, and I believe the answer was that it would actually be more efficient to stop (but we're really at the extremes of aircraft capabilities here).

[This answer over at Aviation.SE](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/47262/how-much-fuel-is-used-for-the-different-phases-of-the-flight-of-a-typical-airlin) tells us that the take-off and climb phase uses about as much fuel as one hour of cruise, but doesn't get into details based on how much fuel is on board/the total weight of the aircraft. You could probably get more detailed figures over there.

Answer (score 8):

Clicking on the "CO2e" figure on Google flights reveals it to be based on passenger seat miles.

Aircraft flying long haul flights have to carry sufficient fuel for diversions and emergencies in addition to the total amount of fuel needed to fly the plane and passengers to their destination.

On shorter haul flights the amount of fuel taken on board for the plane to reach its destination is less (it's a shorter flight) and weighs less. Allowing for requisite tradeoffs, airlines can reduce the amount of fuel taken on board and/or increase the number of seats allocated for the flight, both of which can reduce carbon emisions per passenger mile.

The savings come from not having to burn fuel to take off and carry a long way before it needs to be fed into the aircraft's engines. Or to put it another way, the fuel burned on the second half of a long distance flight would not need to loaded onto the aircraft if the flight only covered half the distance (roughly speaking of course).

If you break a long haul flight into two shorter flights and refuel at a stop over, you keep the fuel savings of the shorter legs, but add the cost of an additional landing, takeoff and hull pressurization cycle. From the figures this will affect CO2e estimations for the total flight, but they will also be influenced by aircraft design and efficiency.

Comment: Doesn't any substantial flight need to carry fuel for diversions and emergencies?

Comment: @LoremIpsum I would hope so and I didn't mean to imply the requirement didn't apply to shorter routes, although the amount of fuel required for diverging may vary depending on how far away from land or alternate airports the route reaches. I'm  not a load master but believe it might also vary if the route direction has tail winds in one direction and headwinds in the other.

Answer (score 5):

KLM was sued by an environmental company over alleged "greenwashing." I think your gut instinct is correct in that this is not truly possible. Their score may be lower due to the purchase of carbon offsets. IMHO carbon offsets are a bit of a farce. And it appears that KLM is still making inflated claims about their CO2 emissions and I expect a carbon emissions lawsuit will be next.

https://www.theguardian.com/world/2024/mar/20/dutch-airline-klm-misled-customers-green-claims-court-rules